# Jackson + Spring web unable to deserialize unquoted string after modifying message-converters

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-modules

I have a spring controller method which takes a `String` as the entirety of the `RequestBody` like so:

```java
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody DTO method(@PathVariable("userId") long userId, @RequestBody String page) {
         // Controller contents here
     }
```

Previously, I have been able to post "naked" strings to this method, that is requests with a string as the body (and not a json object). For example (from chrome dev tools):

[image: Initial post attempt]

This stopped working after I attempted to add a [Jackson Hibernate 4 module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate) to the [Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html) (to deal with hibernate lazy collections), using the following in my xml config file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                    <property name="modulesToInstall"
                              value="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module"/>
                    <property name="featuresToEnable">
                        <array>
                            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES"/>
                        </array>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

After customising the ObjectMapper like this I receive the following error when posting the request as above:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'Testing': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5e6a19fe; line: 1, column: 13]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Testing': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5e6a19fe; line: 1, column: 13]
```

A work arround for this (using angular js) is to call `JSON.stringify()` before posting to the API, so the angular code becomes

```
$http.post(Url + userId, JSON.stringify(string)).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });
```

and the request becomes

[image: With quotes]

After this the API works as it did previously, accepting the String on its own.

While I know that a string without enclosing `"` is not a valid JSON string, what I don't understand is why changing the ObjectMapper bean should make such a difference in this case? I am using spring version 4.3.4 and jackson version 2.8.5, if that's at all useful information.

Answer (score 0):

What did your dispatcher servlet configuration and dependency configuration look like before you introduced a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`?

Since Spring uses the `Content-type` header of your request to determine which message converter to use, why would you explicitly send `application/json` when your request body obviously isn't JSON?

A proper "workaround" would be to send `Content-type: text/plain`, which would make Spring use the `StringHttpMessageConverter` which is also what I believe Spring did before you started configuring a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`

Comment: Dispatcher servlet looked like [this](http://pastie.org/private/s5e1lpwrvfluoeyuj1nifa). There is nothing in my application context related to jackson: I think it's just using spring defaults. I find that even adding the `<mvc:message-converters>` tag is enough to trigger this behaviour. I will look into using `Content-type: text/plain`, but I'm just amazed that attempting to customise the message converters has this effect. Alas, the code has been built in a number of places relying on this, so changing it will be a bit painful but the right thing to do overall.